# Combine the value from a key with all array entries

Tags: jq

I have json input as follows:

```
   [{
    "a": "123",
    "b": [
        "xyz",
        "uvw"
    ]
   }, {
    "a": "456",
    "b": [
        "ghi"
    ]
   }]
```

and I'd like to produce a list where each object's "a" is combined with each element of "b" using a delimiter.  Is this possible to do using jq?

```
123|xyz
123|uvw
456|ghi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the delimiter on the fly if you parameterize it.

```
$ jq -r --arg delim '|' '.[] | "\(.a)\($delim)\(.b[])"' input.json
```